# tcp send at uno openoffice command by telnet or netcat

Tags: telnet, netcat, uno

Hi i try to send command to calc of openoffice ,i want send simple hello world in first cell, i try to call in this mode first i call
`libreoffice --calc --accept="socket,host=localhost,port=2002;urp;StarOffice.ServiceManager`
and  after i try to connect  netcat 127.0.0.1 2002 , it answer me `e��'com.sun.star.bridge.XProtocolPropertiesUrpProtocolProperties.UrpProtocolPropertiesTid�H!�`
but if i try to send  something not answer, anyone know how to do that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do a deep dive into the Universal Network Object protocol (UNO), which was created back in the wild days when OLE, CORBA, and other RPC-like standards were duking it out. See this for an example:
https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Uno/Remote/Specifications/Uno_Remote_Protocol

There's lots more. Good luck.